# Regular Expression Finding the Space before the Last word

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm trying to find the space before the last word of a string.

For example, for

```
Bob Jane
```

I would want to find the space right before Jane. I am trying to do a find and replace all to make that become a comma. Thus, the final result would be

```
Bob ,Jane
```

I'm only doing this in a text editor (using Sublime) so I'm not using a programming language. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[ ](?=[^ ]+$)
```

You can try this.Replace by `,`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oL9kE8/17

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I would upvote as well but can't since I just started on my account.

Answer (score 1):

Find What:

```
 (\S+ *)$
```

REplacement string:

```
,\1
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gC1iN7/2)

If you want to add a comma after to the space which exists before the last word then try the below regex.

```
(?<= )(\S+ *)$
```

Replacement string:

```
,\1
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gC1iN7/3)

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I accepted a previous answer but thanks a lot anyway! I would upvote but I cannot since I just started using my account.

Comment: note that the regex in the accepted answer would replace the last space to comma. https://regex101.com/r/oL9kE8/18 not the space before the last word.